No network drivers installed
On kubuntu 24.04 I have :
inxi -ni
Returns drivers to N/A for all network cards (wifi & ethernet)
How to overcome this problem?

Describe your hardware. [Edit] your Question  to improve it. Do not reply via Add Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

after a thorough investigation, I did:
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic

et voilà
